# How do I get an instruction trace on Mac OS X 10.5 PPC?

Tags: performance, macos, profiling, powerpc

Apple used to ship a tool called `amber` as part of CHUD with Xcode 2.5, which would allow you to get an instruction trace for a process.  You could then feed the instruction trace to `simg5`.  The `simg5` tool shipped with Xcode 3 but without `amber`, which makes it kind of worthless (unless you have a bunch of traces lying around).

How do I get an instruction trace of an OS X / PowerPC process?

(I tried installing `amber` from the Xcode 2.5 packages, but the package refused to run.  I tried extracting the executable manually, but I get a bus error after I attach to a running process, killing both `amber` and the target process.)

Comment: Install 10.4? Apple seems to have slowly dropped support for CHUD; Shark is now replaced by the sampler in Instruments (which doesn't quite do all the same things; in particular I'm not sure you can sample an arbitrary iPhone process anymore). It also might be worth trying to extract the old libraries `amber` linked to.

Comment: Amber appeared to have no dependencies on funny libraries, so 10.4 is my most probable route.  I'll "get" to repartition my hard drive.  Oh well, there are a couple classic apps I wanted to be able to run anyway.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that there are still people out there who care about PPC, let alone optimizing for PPC! I've recently acquired a PowerBook G4 to go with my iBook G4 so I might get around to using 10.5 at home (no G5 yet, sadly...).